# Wordpress. List pages except certain pages

Tags: wordpress

I am using this code to display the pages in a menu:

```
wp_list_pages('title_li=&');
```

There are a few pages that I would like to exclude from the list.

How would I do this please?

Note: I am using friendly URL's so the id's are actually names not numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
 wp_list_pages('title_li'=>'&', 'exclude'=> '1,5,7');
```

where 1,5,7 is id of pages you want to exclude from list. comma separated.

Comment: Should be  wp_list_pages('title_li=&exclude=1,5,7');

Comment: I have friendly urls and not numbers ... how do I use it in this case? Pages, post's have no ID?

Comment: @Satch3000: all pages, regardless of how you view them (aka friendly permalinks), have ID's. Hover your mouse over the link and you'll the page ID (or post ID).

Comment: I've tried that but I just get the page name, sometimes separented but - so about us page comes out as about-us etc... no numbers here :o/

Comment: Go to Wordpress admin, then pages, and when you select a page, the url will be like `/post.php?post=PAGE_ID&action=edit`.